# Inserting PDF into InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been supplied with a PDF that I need to insert into InDesign. The particular InDesign document is a 16pp booklet, so there are facing pages. The PDF is going on a facing page. The PDF is set up with a 3mm bleed (which matches that of the InDesign document), so obviously there are crop marks. What's the best way to insert the PDF in the right position and remove the crop marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute easiest? Move in the edges of your picture box to cover the crops.

If the PDF is a multi page PDF, check the options box in your window and it will let you select which page you want to place.

Comment: And if the placed PDFs have some bleed, then only crop the image off on the inner margin – the spine. It is absolutely not necessary to crop the PDF to exactly the same size as the pages. If the crop marks already fall outside the page boundary, you can leave them as they are.

Answer (score 1):

I would crop the PDF to remove the printers marks. In Adobe Acrobat Pro:

Open the PDF and select `Document > Crop Pages` and select `Trim Box`

You could then place the PDF in line with your document edges as if it were a standard asset.

Answer (score 0):

No need to crop in Acrobat Pro. 
The PDF will be held in a picture box when you place the PDF on the page. Just grab each edge of the picture box and move it over the PDF until it covers the unwanted crop marks (and any other printer's marks).